# How can I be outranked by another site that objectively worse in every way: metrics from majestic, Alexa rank, plus a poor design

Tags: seo, google, keywords, search-results, ranking

- My website:

  - 29 trust flow
  - 33 citation flow
  - 15 domain authority
  - 15 page authority
  - 370 back links
  - no Alexa ranking
- The other website:

  - 1 trust flow
  - 5 citation flow
  - 3 domain authority
  - 3 page authority
  - 4 million Alexa rank

Why for the same 3 keywords is the other site in the 5th position and my site is in 25th?

So I search for "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3", their domain contains "keyword1-keyword2" and the URL path contains "keyword1", "keyword2" and "keyword3". The H1 also contains "keyword1" and "keyword2". The meta description contains only "keyword1" and "keyword2".

The domain of my website does not contain any of those keywords. The page URL contains "keyword1" and "keyword2".   My meta description contains "keyword1", "keyword2" and "keyword3". The H1 and H2 contain "keyword1," "keyword2" and "keyword3."

So basically I don't really understand how can such a website rank higher than me + the website is poor regarding the design and it doesn't even have a favicon.  I really don't understand how is this possible
Maybe anyone could explain or maybe I don't see something important.

Comment: I remove the term "meta title" from your post and replaced it with "meta description".   There is no such thing as a "meta title".   It is also possible that you meant "page title" which is not a meta element.  If so, you should edit your post to correct my correction.

Comment: You seem to be the type of person who puts too much faith in matrix's offered by SEO companies, solely for profit.

Comment: Metrics aside a huge ranking factor is link building you should check what kind of links are pointing to your competitor and what links are pointing to your site.

Comment: John Could - i've checked this direct competitor has 1 backlink from a domain Z which TF 13 not very hight but domain Z has 6000 backlinks, could this be a reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google rankings are complicated.  It is difficult to understand the rankings in any given case.  Google says they use over 200 factors in making ranking decisions.

Here a list of possible factors that could be playing a big role which you did not mention:

- **Page age and domain age**: If your site in newer, Google may take some time to trust it, even as it gains some good links.  The age of the site may matter more to Google than some of the trust factors that Majestic is looking at
- **Usability factors**: Google may measure how users react to your site.  If Google thinks users react better to the other site, Google may prefer it.  You need to ask "Does my site satisfy the users that have done this search?  Does it give them what they are looking for clearly, easily, and cheaply?"
- **Anchor text**: Are they links pointing to your competition that use the keywords in the anchor text?  If so, those may be having a big effect.
- **Site speed and mobile friendly**: Does your site outperform the other site in terms of speed and how well it works on mobile devices?   Have you tested this with Google's tools?
- **Penalties**: Is there anything your site has done that may be lowering its ranking?   Are you *over optimizing* the keywords in your page and using them *too much*? Could Google think any of your links are unnatural?  Anything else in Google's webmaster guidelines that could be problems?

If you want even more possibilities, see [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)